# Implication of Xがよい

Tags: usage, etymology

I often see phrases of the form Xがよい (where X is a noun) e.g. 頭がよい, 仲がよい etc. In these examples the characteristic being described is desirable (clever, good relationship etc) so よい seems sensible.

I came across 肉付きがよい recently. Perhaps I misunderstand the term but I assume it means fat/chubby; a characteristic which in many (most?) cultures is not seen as desirable.

So my question is, is Xがよい neutral, i.e can it be used for non-desirable characteristics too?
Or perhaps, when the phrase was first used, being fat was as sign of status and richness and so was seen as a desirable characteristic.

Are there other examples of Xがよい like this?

Comment: can it be used for non-desirable characteristics -- 「虫がいい」とか

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would characterize「肉付きがよい」as more along the lines of "stout" or "well-fed".  That is, it is generally talking about being overweight a bit, but not in a particularly derogatory way, but more in a "well off"/"not lacking nourishment" sort of sense.

I think it's fairly similar to the many expressions we have in English that might phrase being overweight in a somewhat nice-sounding way to be more polite or kind about it ("big boned", "plump", "jolly", "stout", etc).

It's also worth noting, though, that よい/いい does not always mean "good" in a value-judgement sort of way ("good" vs "bad"), but can often just mean "a good amount"/"sufficient"/"substantial"/etc.  So in this sense you can also interpret「肉付きがよい」to just mean something like "a *substantial amount* of meat on (their) bones", etc, too.

Answer (score 1):

肉付きが良い could be used as a euphemism for fat, but by itself does not have negative implications. (Possibly similar to *voluptuous*?)

Another example that could be used in a sarcastic way is 育ちが良い, to make fun of someone being ignorant of things the commons should know. Similarly, 行儀が良い can mean negatively *too good mannered*. Again, these are about how they are used, and the words themselves just mean *well-bred*/*good-mannered*.